# django fetch users with profile

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a model User and UserProfile. I need to get a list of users with their user profiles.
I need to do a sort of "table join" so that the fetched users will have profiles included.
I know I can just do

```
User.objects.all()
```

and in the template, I just do

```
user.get_profile
```

But the problem is I won't be using this in a template. I am creating a rest api for my frontend using django. I need the fetched users to already have a profile so that I can retrieve their pictures.

I tried

```
User.objects.all().select_related('user__userprofile')
```

But after serialization, the returned objects would not have a profile. The return looks somewhat like:

```
{pk:7,model: auth.user,fields:{...}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select related forms a SQL query that would fetch related data on evaluation (which saves you a query). Your serializer won't pick up related data magically.

Write or find a proper serializer for your requirement or have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list